# Extrema for the functions of two variables

Tags: functional-analysis

I made some calculations and got that (0,0) is a critical point for the function:

$f(x,y)=4x^3-2x^2y+y^2$

But can someone please help me  determine its nature?

Comment: The determinant of the hessian matrix

Comment: Have you computed the hessian matrix?

Comment: Maybe I have errors in calculation,but I got that the hesian of (0,0) is equal to zero

Comment: Ok what to do in this case if the hessian is equal to zero

Comment: You ought to edit your calculations into the original post

Comment: Well, what would you do if you had a single-variable function for which both the first and second derivatives vanished at some point?